# Send/receive notifications

Tags: c#, notifications, push-notification

I have an Outlook add-in and a separate winform app. These two apps need to "talk" together sending/receiving notifications.

Sometimes they are on the same computer and sometimes they are on different computers. Sometimes several instances runs on the same computer by different users (RDS server). Maybe later they will need to talk to mobile apps too.

If I do no want to play around with TCPIP, what is the best and easiset way? I don't mind buying some server software that will make it easier. It must be plug-and-play.

I thought about Microsoft Notification HUB, but it doesn't seam like it works with winform.

Then there is Amazon SNS, but I have no experience if this works in winform.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to develop real time notification system it easy and you can use it cross platform because it uses websockets like node js

Comment: Great idea ... I have some issues with Outlook then .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057480/signalr-outlook-add-in-and-multithread-exception